# BottomSheetScaffold doesn't stick to the top of BottomNavigation when expanded

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-bottomnav

I am trying to use BottomSheetScaffold but for some weird reason when I use it on a screen with bottom navigation and expand the bottomSheet the bottom side of it moves a little bit to the top, but when I remove the bottom navigation everything works as expected!

Does anyone have an idea why that is happening? and how can I fix it?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ContainerView() {
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

    val appBarHeight = getAppBarHeight(
        scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.offset.value,
        scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.targetValue
    )
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        BottomSheetScaffold(
            sheetContent = {
                BottomSheetContent(
                    appBarHeight = appBarHeight
                )
            },
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            sheetPeekHeight = 100.dp,
            sheetBackgroundColor = greysWhite,
            sheetShape = Shapes.extraLarge
                .copy(bottomEnd = CornerSize(0), bottomStart = CornerSize(0))
        ) {

            Text("Hello World")
        }
        Surface(elevation = 14.dp) {
            AppBar(
                modifier = Modifier,
                appBarHeight = appBarHeight
            ) { }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomSheetContent(
    appBarHeight: Dp,
) {
    val padding by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = appBarHeight,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = animationDuration)
    )
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = padding)
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
    ) {
        repeat((0..22).count()) {
            Text("$it", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

[image][image]

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is moving to the top of screen when you use BottomSheetScaffold?

Comment: when I expand the bottom sheet, the bottom of the bottom sheet moves along with it as you can see in the right image after number 13 you will see the bottom of the bottom sheet

Comment: Well yes, that is the usecase of a BottomSheetScaffold. It does open up along the screen. If you want something like a bottom sheet above your screen content, you can go with [ModalBottomSheet](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/bottom-sheets)

Comment: I don't think you understood my explanation, I updated the screenshot. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Okay I think i get it. That padding must probably be the inset padding that you may have given. 
Check if you set something like below:
`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)`
If yes, change the flag to false and try again.

Comment: nope, I didn't use any inset padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the Material library version that I was using.

I was using this version `androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.1`
but after updating the dependency to this version `1.6.0-alpha05` It worked as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same code of yours below with a sample Bottom Navigation and there is no padding on bottom of bottom sheet while using it. Please check the below code.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ContainerView() {
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetContent = {
            BottomSheetContent(
            )
        },
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = 100.dp,
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
        sheetShape = Shapes().large
            .copy(bottomEnd = CornerSize(0), bottomStart = 
CornerSize(0))
    ) {

        Text("Hello World")
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        BottomNavigationView()
    }
}
}

@Composable
fun BottomSheetContent(
) {

val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
) {
    repeat((0..22).count()) {
        Text("$it", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
    }
}
}

@Composable
fun BottomNavigationView() {
val items = listOf(
    "Home",
    "MyNetwork",
    "AddPost",
    "Notification",
    "Job"
)
BottomNavigation(
    backgroundColor = Color.Cyan,
    contentColor = Color.Black
) {
    
    items.forEach { item ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = {  },
            label = { Text(text = item,
                fontSize = 9.sp) },
            selectedContentColor = Color.Black,
            unselectedContentColor = Color.Black.copy(0.4f),
            alwaysShowLabel = true,
            selected = false,
            onClick = {

            }
        )
    }
}
}
```